# How to mimic spring @Scheduled behavior with quartz Scheduler?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

Given the constraint that I must use quartz's [Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/) which is used in the context of a cluster and configured with a JDBC data source.

How can I mimic spring's [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) behavior, i.e. don't persist the job, don't ensure there's only one node per cluster executing the job. Just run that method of that bean at specified interval/delay.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot mix both types of jobs in the same Scheduler.

The usual approach is to create create a different `Scheduler` using a `RAMJobStore` to run the jobs that shouldn't be clustered jobs, so you'll end up with two `Scheduler` instances in your app.